# Search array for a value [swift]

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

Just started learning swift, spent a few hours trying to figure this out by searching here but no luck so far.

I have an array, created like this:

```
class ProbabilitiesClass {
    var list = [Odds]()

    init() {
        list.append(Odds(dateInit: -35, oddsTodayInit: "0,01", sevenDaysInit: "0,2"))
        list.append(Odds(dateInit: -34, oddsTodayInit: "0,01", sevenDaysInit: "0,3"))
        list.append(Odds(dateInit: -33, oddsTodayInit: "0,02", sevenDaysInit: "0,4"))
```

I want to search first parameter of this array for an integer and return its index.

Tried this

```
if let i = Odds.firstIndex(where: { $0.hasPrefix(differenceInDays) }) {
    print("index is \([i])")
}
```

It returns error:

> Type 'Odds' has no member 'firstIndex'

The end goal is to return second and third parameters of that index.

Update: I defined Odds like this:

```
import Foundation

class Odds {
    let dateText : Int
    let oddsToday : String
    let odds7Days : String

    init(dateInit: Int, oddsTodayInit: String, sevenDaysInit : String) {
        dateText = dateInit
        oddsToday = oddsTodayInit
        odds7Days = sevenDaysInit
    }

}
```

Comment: You want `list.firstIndex`. But then `$0` will be a reference to an `Odds` instance.

Comment: thank you, trying now. So it's not an exactly an array I created, is it a list?

Comment: It is an array. And the name of the variable is `list`.

Comment: Sounds like you should spend some quality time reading the [Collection Types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html) chapter of the Swift book (along with the rest of the book).

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want to achieve? You want index of element with specific prefix?

Comment: Thanks, rmaddy!  @AndriusSteponavičius I want to search this array for an Integer (dateInit) and get the corresponding second (oddsTodayInit) and third (sevenDaysInit) parameters

Comment: How have you defined `Odds`?

Comment: @Carpsen90 Added definition to my question, please see above

Comment: Your naming is really bad. Don't put the suffix "init" on your the parameters to your initializer.  `init(date:oddsToday:sevenDays:)` is a much better name for an initializer. Also, a field `dateText` that's an Int is really misleading.

Comment: Makes sense, will update the naming. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like so:

```
let p = ProbabilitiesClass()
let differenceInDays = -34
if let i = p.list.firstIndex(where: { $0.dateText == differenceInDays }) {
    print("index is \([i])")   //index is [1]
}
```

Look for the index in the `list` property of an instance of `ProbabilitiesClass`. And like the error message says: The class `Odds` is not an array to use the method `firstIndex(where:)` on it.

---

If you want to use the properties of the first element which has its `dateInit` equal to `differenceInDays`, then you could do it like so:

```
if let first = p.list.first(where: { $0.dateText == differenceInDays }) {
    print("oddsTodayInit =", first.oddsToday)
    print("sevenDaysInit =", first.odds7Days)
}
```

It uses this function [`first(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1848165-first).

Comment: The property of `Odds` is named `dateText` (but it's an `Int`.) The parameter on the initializer is called `dateInit`.